# T-SQL: How to add string at a certain index of another string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a table called `EmailTemplates`, which has the column `MessageText`. For each row, I'd like to add a `Please review details` before `Thank you`.  For some rows, there might text after `thank you`.

**BEFORE**

```
All the correspondence will be sent to your address.

Thank you!
```

**AFTER**

```
All the correspondence will be sent to your address.

Please review details

Thank you!
```

I don't know whether `REPLACE` is the right function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on whether you want to replace ALL instances of 'Thank you' with 'Please review details Thank you' or just the last one.  The implementation below, whilst awfully hacky, shows you how it is possible to do both (although if this is for production use I'd strongly recommend refactoring the code to make it less messy).

```
declare @myTestTable as table
(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered,
    textValue varchar(500) not null
);

insert into @myTestTable(textValue)
values 
    ('All correspondence will be sent to your addres.  Thank you!'),
    ('I will get back to you.  Thank you for your patience'),
    ('Thank you for calling us up'),
    ('You didn''t have to do what you did, but I thank you for it, so thank you!');


select m.*, REPLACE(m.textValue, 'thank you', 'Please review details.  Thank you') as blindReplace,
    SUBSTRING(m.textValue, 0, len(m.textValue) - CHARINDEX(reverse('thank you'), reverse(m.textValue)) + 2 - len('thank you'))
        + 'Please review details ' +
    SUBSTRING(m.textValue, len(m.textValue) - CHARINDEX(reverse('thank you'), reverse(m.textValue)) + 2 -len('thank you'), len(m.textValue)) as lastReplace

from @myTestTable as m
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE EmailTemplates
SET MessageText = LEFT(MessageText, LEN(MessageText) - 10) + 'Please review details.

Thank You!'
```

Comment: Why are you using `LEN`? Is there a way just to replace `Thank you`? In fact, depending on the row, there might be some text after `Thank you!`.

Comment: @Richard77 From OP `before the last sentence, which is Thank you.`. The keyword is **last**.

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE` *can* be used in your situation, and an example of how to use it was in the now deleted answer by @juergen d: Here it is again (slightly changed to better match):

```
UPDATE EmailTemplates
SET MessageText = REPLACE(ColumnName, 'Thank you!', 'Please review details.

Thank you!')
WHERE MessageText LIKE '%Thank you!%';
```

You can use a multiline replacement string like above or you can encode EOLs with `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`:

```
REPLACE(
  ColumnName,
  'Thank you!',
  'Please review details.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'Thank you!'
)
```

There is also method which uses `STUFF` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
UPDATE EmailTemplates
SET MessageText = STUFF(
  ColumnName,
  CHARINDEX('Thank you!', ColumnName),
  0,
  'Please review details.

'
)
WHERE MessageText LIKE '%Thank you!%';
```

This method is certainly more verbose. Technically, it is not strictly equivalent to `REPLACE`, because `REPLACE` processes all occurrences of the search term and `STUFF` applies to just one specific position/fragment of the string. But if `Thank you!` cannot occur more than once in a template, the two methods can be considered equivalent.